# Order a sentence alphabetically and count the number of times each words appears and print in a table

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling with the print in a table part of the question. So far I have managed to order the user inputted sentence alphabetically and count the number of times each word occurs. Here is the code:

```
thestring = (raw_input())
sentence = thestring.split(" ")
sentence.sort()

count = {}
for word in thestring.split():
    try: count[word] += 1
    except KeyError: count[word] = 1

print sentence
print count
```

And when I run the code I get this:

```
['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'orange', 'pear', 'pear', 'strawberry']
{'apple': 2, 'pear': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'mango': 1, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 1}
```

However, ideally I want it printed in a table that looks something like:

```
apple.....|.....2
banana....|.....1
mango.....|.....1
orange....|.....1
pear......|.....2
strawberry|.....1
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sentence = thestring.split(" ")
from collections import Counter
for fruit, num in sorted(Counter(sentence).items()):
    print "{:10}|{:5}".format(fruit.ljust(10, "."), str(num).rjust(5, "."))
```

**Output**

```
apple.....|....2
banana....|....1
mango.....|....1
orange....|....1
pear......|....2
strawberry|....1
```

You can use the [format examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to understand how it works.

Comment: This answer deserves to be accepted. If you'd just add info about Counter, I'll upvote! :)

Comment: From my understanding, they want the output to be sorted.

Comment: @thg435 Sorry. I missed that. Updated my solution now. Please check.

Answer (score 5):

[`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) is the pythonic way to print, well, formatted strings:

```
d = {'apple': 2, 'pear': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'mango': 1, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 1}

for word, count in sorted(d.items()):
    print "{:20} | {:5}".format(word, count)
```

To resize the first column automatically:

```
maxlen = max(map(len, d))
for word, count in sorted(d.items()):
    print "{:{}} | {}".format(word, maxlen, count)
```

If you really want to fill it up with dots (or whatever), then like this:

```
for word, count in sorted(d.items()):
    print "{:.<{}}|{:.>5}".format(word, maxlen, count)
```

```
apple.....|....2
banana....|....1
mango.....|....1
orange....|....1
pear......|....2
strawberry|....1
```

As already pointed out, for the first part it's better to use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Comment: But the question remains, how do you fill up format with `.`s instead of spaces.

Comment: This seems even more interesting than rjust and ljust. Upvoted :)

Comment: @thg435 Awesome :) I learn from guys like you everyday in SO. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `collections.Counter` for that:

```
from collections import Counter

thestring = (raw_input()).split(" ")
cnt = Counter(thestring)
items = cnt.items()
items.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print items
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is the better solution, but if you want to stick to your code, just replace `print count` by

```
for c in sorted(count): 
    print c + '.'*(10-len(c))+'|'+'.'*(6-len(str(count[c])))+str(count[c])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'apple': 2, 'pear': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'mango': 1, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 1}
for v,k in d.items():
  s = str(v).ljust(l, '.') + "|" + str(k).rjust(10, '.')
  print s
```

Where l is lenght of u longest key.

And on output you have:

```
apple.....|.........2
pear......|.........2
strawberry|.........1
mango.....|.........1
orange....|.........1
banana....|.........1
```